# Send class object to stage controller - javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I have a class FontInfo and i try to send its object myFont to new controller of stage which appear when i click button. Here is my main controller class:

```
public class MainController {

//create instance of font
private FontInfo myFont;

@FXML
private Button btnChooseFont;

public void initialize()
{
    //create new myFont
    myFont = new FontInfo();
}

@FXML
void actionBtnChooseFont(ActionEvent event) {

    try
    {
        //resource to new parent root
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../fxml/ChooseFont.fxml"));
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("Choose font");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 290));
        stage.show();

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("../fxml/ChooseFont.fxml"));
        ChooseFontController chooseFontController = loader.getController();
        chooseFontController.setMyFont(myFont);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

I need to use myFont object which I create in MainConroller in ChooseFontController class :

```
public class ChooseFontController {

//myFont object
private FontInfo myFont;

//setter myFont
public void setMyFont(FontInfo myFont) {
    this.myFont = myFont;
}
```

But i get null pointer exception error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at controllers.MainController.actionBtnChooseFont(MainController.java:48)
```

in :`chooseFontController.setMyFont(myFont);`

Can anyone help me with this issue ?

Comment: It seems like the FXMLLoader couldn't find a Controller, and therefore returns null from the `loader.getController()`. Maybe calling `loader.load()` helps finding it ;). (Ps. Debugging helps a lot in these cases to find the exact problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the FXMLLoader couldn't find a Controller, and therefore returns null from the `loader.getController()`. Maybe calling `loader.load()` helps finding it... e.g.

```
  FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("../fxml/ChooseFont.fxml"));
  Loader.load();
  ChooseFontController chooseFontController = loader.getController();
  chooseFontController.setMyFont(myFont);
```

(Ps. Debugging helps a lot in these cases to find the exact problem)

Answer (score 1):

Modify `initialize method`:

```
@FXML
public void initialize()
{
    //create new myFont
    myFont = new FontInfo();
}
```

---

Actually the problem is that you never load the `ChooseFont.fxml` document so you have to edit your code to load the fxml document:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("../fxml/ChooseFont.fxml"));
try{
  loader.load();
}catch(Exception ex){
 ex.printStackTrace();
}
ChooseFontController chooseFontController = loader.getController();
```

---

Also keep in mind that here you are using a static constructor

```
 Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../fxml/ChooseFont.fxml"));
```